# How to translate contains condition statement in mongodb query using pymongo to get data in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, mongodb-query

I'm trying to load Mongodb data into pandas dataframe. Can somebody help me to correctly translate the following query part (contains condition) to use it within python:

```
{ "Url": /.*certain_string.*/i }
```

Right now I load everything and then remove the extras by the following command:

```
df = df[df['Url'].str.contains('certain_string')]
```

but with this approach I load a lot of extra data for no reason.

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to first compile your regex, then use the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'*.certain_string.*', re.I)
db.collection.find({'Url': {'$regex': pat}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas groupby(), filter(), agg(), apply(), etc. are your friends.

See the [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) and [transformation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) (the latter more so) in Group By:split-apply-combine Pandas documentation. Use a regular expression for the filter parameter.

Comment: I can certainly use those friends, but before that I don't want to load into pandas dataframe millions of records from Mongodb. I just want to improve the query part

Comment: Then select a subset of the the MongoDB data using regex as joao suggests. I was approaching this as a Pandas question, but if you don't ever want the data to ever enter into the dataframe (rather than post processing) then what you're asking is a MongoDB question.

Answer (score 0):

With a big help from joao, Sean and google, I found a solution for my question:

import re

pat = re.compile(r'.*\Qcertain_string\E.*')

db.collection.find({'Url': {'$regex': pat}})

Comment: Your "pat" variable did not work at all. Compare the answers. I really appreciate and used your help, but had to completely change the pat variable. It won't work for anyone who has a similar issue.

Comment: What do you mean by *it didn't work*? you put a placeholder in your question and I used it in my answer. This is how we do it here.

Comment: You are right, I accept your answer. Sorry, I am completely novice here. The problem is that pymongo query syntax is different than mongodb query and that's what I was asking